# How to obtain new samples from ZIP or ZINB-model for bayesian p-value

Tags: r, bayesian, glm, poisson, jags

Hopefully someone can help me with this one, because I am really stuck and do not find my coding error!

I am fitting zero-inflated poisson / negative binomial GLMs (no random effects) in JAGS (with R2Jags) and everything is fine with the parameter estimates, priors, initial values and chains convergence. All results are perfectly in line with, e.g., the estimates from the pscl-package, including my calculation of pearson residuals in the model...

The only thing I cannot get to work is to sample from the model a new sample to obtain a bayesian p-value for evaluating the model fit. The "normal" poisson and negative binomial models I fit before all gave the expected replicated samples and no problems occured.

Here's my code so far, but the important part is "#New Samples":

```
model{
# 1. Priors
beta  ~ dmnorm(b0[], B0[,])   
aB    ~ dnorm(0.001, 1)

    #2. Likelihood function
    for (i in 1:N){  

    # Logistic part
    W[i]           ~ dbern(psi.min1[i])
    psi.min1[i]   <- 1 - psi[i]
    eta.psi[i]    <- aB
    logit(psi[i]) <- eta.psi[i]

    # Poisson part
    Y[i]           ~ dpois(mu.eff[i])
    mu.eff[i]     <- W[i] * mu[i]
    log(mu[i])    <- max(-20, min(20, eta.mu[i]))
    eta.mu[i]     <- inprod(beta[], X[i,])

    # Discrepancy measures:
    ExpY[i]       <- mu [i] * (1 - psi[i])
    VarY[i]       <- (1- psi[i]) * (mu[i] + psi[i] * pow(mu[i], 2))
    PRes[i]       <- (Y[i] - ExpY[i]) / sqrt(VarY[i])
    D[i]          <- pow(PRes[i], 2)

    # New Samples:
    YNew[i]        ~ dpois(mu.eff[i])
    PResNew[i]    <- (YNew[i] - ExpY[i]) / sqrt(VarY[i])
    DNew[i]       <- pow(PResNew[i], 2)
    } 
Fit         <- sum(D[1:N])
FitNew      <- sum(DNew[1:N])
}
```

The big problem is, that I really tried all combinations and alterations I think could/should work, but when I look at the simulated samples, I get this here:

```
> all.equal( Jags1$BUGSoutput$sims.list$YNew, Jags1$BUGSoutput$sims.list$Y )

[1] TRUE
```

And, to make it really weird, when using the means of Fit and FitNew:

```
> Jags1$BUGSoutput$mean$Fit
[1] 109.7883
> Jags1$BUGSoutput$mean$FitNew
[1] 119.2111
```

Has anyone a clue what I am doing wrong? Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Kind regards, Ulf

Comment: you are using `Jags1$BUGSoutput$sims.list$Y`, but this does not make sense, since Y is data, not output parameter, so it shouldn't have any simulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this isn't the case, but the only obvious reason I can suspect for Y[i] and YNew[i] being always identical is if mu.eff[i] is ~zero, either because W[i] is 0 or mu[i] is close to zero.  This implies that Y[] is always zero, which is easy to check from your data, but as I said it does seem odd that you would be trying to model this...  Otherwise, I'm not sure what is going on ... try simplifying the code to see if that solves the problem, and then add things back in until it breaks again.  Some other suggestions:

- It may be helpful for debugging to look at the absolute values of Y and YNew rather than just Y==YNew
- If you want a negative binomial (= gamma-Poisson) try sampling mu[i] from a gamma distribution - I have used this formulation for ZINB models extensively, so am sure it works
- Your prior for aB looks odd to me - it gives a prior 95% CI for zero inflation around 12-88% - is that what you intended? And why a mean of 0.001 not 0?  If you have no predictors then a beta prior for psi.min seems more natural - and if you have no useful prior information a beta(1,1) prior would be an obvious choice.
- Minor point but you are calculating a lot of deterministic functions of aB within the for loop - this is going to slow down your model...

Hope that helps,

Matt

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did compare the absolute values of Y and YNew as you suggested which brought me to the answer, because the Y-values I saw were not all integers as they should be being the original data...

Comment: And a second thank you because you pointed me to the too narrow prior for aB! To put the aB into the loop just comes from the plan to later add predictors and with aB inside the loop I do not have to change more things to get an extended model running...!

Answer (score 0):

So, after getting a nervous breakdown and typing all again and again while searching for my coding error, I found the most stupid error I have ever made - so far:

I just did not specify "Y" as a parameter to save, only "YNew", so when I compared YNew and Y from the sims.list with all.equal, I did not get what I thought I should. I do not know why JAGS gives me the Y at all (from the sims.list of the JAGS-object), but for some reason it is just giving me YNew when asked to give Y. So this part is actually right:

> Jags1$BUGSoutput$mean$Fit
>   [1] 109.7883
>   Jags1$BUGSoutput$mean$FitNew
>   [1] 119.2111

So I hope that I did not cause a major confusion for anybody...

Comment: Glad the answer helped. Note that it is not actually JAGS or rjags that are returning 'Y' for YNew - it is the r2jags package (which I assume you are using) sitting between you and JAGS that has caused this!  It has arisen from the fact that some (but not all) of the methods for extracting elements of lists in R do partial matching - so basically this has happened:   mylist <- list(YNew='whatever');  mylist$Y    - trying to access mylist['Y'] on the other hand results in the expected NULL being returned.